# datepicker in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I use Date Picker in My App I want that when I select Date from date Picker and click on Done button I need to list all the things from some other class in Some view Which is occur on that particular date which I selected.Which view is best for me to display that list of things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you told you have created datePicker so when you click on done Button.

**1)** Store Corresponding data into Array, so that you can show that data on to the `UItableView`.

**2)** Create TableView :here you only need to create the TableView and show those data.Suppose have collected the data in your Array(As in step 1).

Follow Given Steps for Creating Data in tableView.

**A)** Create Instance of `UItableView` in `UiViewController`.h class in Which you want to Show The TableView

```
AS `UITableView *myTableView`;
```

**B)** Adopt The UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate protocol in ViewController Where you going to show TableView

C)Create Table (programmatically or by IB(Interface Builder)
here i am showing Programmatically

```
//you may call this Method View Loading Time.    
-(void)createTable{
    CGrect yourFrame=CGrectMake(0,20,320,400);//Set Desired Frame of Table;
    myTableView=[[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:yourFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];
    myTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    myTableView.delegate=self;
    myTableView.dataSource=self;
    myTableView.separatorStyle=  UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    myTableView.scrollEnabled=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:myTableView];
}

 //Data Source method to create number of section in Table View
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { 
return 1;   
}

// Data Source method to create number of rows section of a Table View
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [yourMutableArray count];
}
 // Data Source method to create cells in Table View
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    //here you check for PreCreated cell.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //Fill the cells...  
    cell.textLabel.text = [yourMutableArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    //yourMutableArray Contains the Data(When You click On Done Button this array will stored the data).
return cell;
}
```

I Hope It'll really Help You .

Answer (score 1):

I think `UItableView` will be the good option.

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/introduction-to-table-view/

Answer (score 0):

I Think its better to  use Tableview only Since After changing the date u have to change the data also ,So if u use Table view we can just reload the tableview it will be simple

Answer (score -1):

Once you click done button, make a query to get all the data based on the selected data and store it in some array..and reload the table view with the data in the array...